# Virtual Hosting | internal error - server connection terminated

Tags: linux, webserver, virtual-host

so I set up lot's of virtual domains in my career but I can't get macdougall.ninja to load for some reason. I'm stumped on.  The webpage error says:

> internal error - server connection terminated

Here is my Virtual Host file:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
   
    ServerName macdougall.ninja
    ServerAlias www.macdougall.ninja
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/macdougall.ninja/public_html
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/macdougall.ninja-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/macdougall.ninja-access.log combined
    <Directory "/var/www/macdougall.ninja/public_html">
      AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
    
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.macdougall.ninja [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =macdougall.ninja
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} `[END,NE,R=permanent]
```

`

Here is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
 
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Apache status is active. I have other sites loading. I have restarted Apache

OS=Centos7

Comment: what is the output of `apache2ctl configtest`?

Comment: Are you using any /etc/hosts mapping for this domain, or just normal DNS?

Comment: "apachectl configtest" gives me | 

AH00526: Syntax error on line 17 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/orcaaccounting.com-le-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/orcaaccounting.com-0001/cert.pem' does not exist or is empty

Don't think that applies here. SSL error on orcaaccounting.com which loads fine.

Just using DNS with Godaddy, the domain pings and I have the correct A record ip.

Comment: any indications in configured error log? `/var/log/httpd/macdougall.ninja-error.log` <-- maybe the log will help.

Comment: No indications anything is wrong.  The command went through fine output was nothing.

Comment: what command? the configtest? I got that part. I was asking if anything is logged - internal errors are server side error and there should be something logged. is there something in the log file.

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file set up?

Comment: Zina the log is empty, when I cat /var/log/httpd/macdougall.ninja-error.log the command goes through but there is no output.

Davidgo - No htaccess

Comment: an internal error must be logged somewhere. what about standard apache logs? The default error log is often in `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or `/var/log/apache2/error.log` - if you did not redirect them

Comment: @Zina, thanks for the response.  output was too long to post here so | https://termbin.com/rvjk

I read somewhere that maybe a reboot of the modem and computer would work. But this is enterprise linux not crappy windows, I don't feel I should have to do that.  Thoughts?

Comment: well your index.html does not look like using robomail and if other sites are working then it is not the issue. what about permissions of document root? are those correct? compare to other sites which are working.

Comment: Solved! The A record got changed somehow.  This is three times now DNS has changed for me with Godaddy.  So strange. Thanks for the help.

Comment: seems you will need to open a ticket with godaddy....glad to hear you found the issue, thanks for letting us know.